wireless Network and bluetooth Unclaimed in ubuntu 22.04
i have installed ubuntu 22.04 (kernel 6.5.0-44), wireless devices are not working, i did every possible thing i could, suggested on other posts , suggested by google. Still unable to find a proper solution. if anyone can help it'll be grateful for me.
**sudo lshw -class network**
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff memory:6000000000-60000fffff memory:80400000-80407fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 11
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: enxca096e77d72d
       serial: ca:09:6e:77:d7:2d
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=6.5.0-44-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.35.188 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair


Please edit the question and list all the things you have tried and what ever messages or errors you got. This helps so no one tells you to do something you have already done.

Please edit the question to include results from terminal for lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net
